# How do I make a python terminal smaller on start up

Tags: python, windows

Hello I've been learning python for the past week and I've noticed when ever I run the application it always starts up very big
is there any way i could fix this?
image:
[image]

Comment: why are you using the python terminal if you have vscode? also it doesn't seem to be too easy to do, you could use `ctypes` and Windows API to change the size but otherwise the window itself doesn't seem to provide any settings for its size (considering it has no menus)

Comment: You can right-click on the little icon in the upper-left of the windows and select Properties. A dialog will appear and you can set the Window Size on one of the tabs.